# Identify the graphic card is inbuilt or external c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to know that is there a way to identify the graphic card using in our machine is an external or inbuilt one from the code? I am using c++ and opengl.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to know.

Comment: Yeah, I want to change some opengl rendering in my project depending on the fact that video card is external or not.

Comment: External like the [Quadroplex](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadroplex-7000-us.html)?  Or external like a USB [DisplayLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) dongle?

Comment: It is like  Quadroplex. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get the supported extensions? There exist a library called GLEW that is used to get the supported extensions. See [Using GLEW to use OpenGL extensions under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370/using-glew-to-use-opengl-extensions-under-windows)

The alternative is to do an OS specific device query. (so you need to give us an OS before we go that route)

Comment: Thanks Misha. I shall give it a try.