# Opengl superbible example compliation errors Source code: drawing a triangle library

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to OpenGL and I'm now trying examples in the book, I've included all the libraries correctly, but it seems there are still something not going right.

Two libraries: freeglut_static.lib  gltools.lib were included in the project.

This is the code:

```
// Triangle.cpp
// Our first OpenGL program that will just draw a triangle on the screen.
#include <GLTools.h> // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h> // Shader Manager Class
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h> // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h> // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif
GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context.
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
{
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();
    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();
    // Perform the buffer swap to display the back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow(“Triangle”);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, “GLEW Error: %s\n”, glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Error messsages given :

```
 1>Linking...
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Triangle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewGetErrorString@4 referenced in function _main
1>Triangle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0 referenced in function _main
1>D:\XING BIZHOU\project\openglproj\Debug\openglproj.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\XING BIZHOU\project\openglproj\openglproj\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>openglproj - 3 error(s), 2 warning(s)
```

Comment: `_glewGetErrorString` - you need to [add `glew32.lib`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17370/1888983). Also some good results on [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=error+LNK2019%3A+unresolved+external+symbol+_glewGetErrorString%404+referenced+in+function&oq=error+LNK2019%3A+unresolved+external+symbol+_glewGetErrorString%404+referenced+in+function&aqs=chrome..69i57.287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I have added the glew32.lib in the project, but still the same error?

Comment: I understand why, its because I didn't use the library recommended from the book, so it was the version problem, thank you all

Answer (score 1):

```
unresolved external symbol _glewGetErrorString
```

This means the compiler is not finding the `glew32` library in your environment. Try installing it and making sure it is in your `LDPATH` so that your compiler can see it.

Comment: Where can I find  LDPATH?

Comment: It is an _environment variable_. There are several: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH`. Anyway if you install `libglew-dev` from the ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt-get install libglew-dev`) it should already be in your library path.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2008 and I added these libraries manually

Comment: Oh. Then just input your library to Visual Studio. As @Aaron said in his answer, Project/Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies is the place to do this.

Comment: I understand why, its because I didn't use the library recommended from the book, so it was the version problem, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Have you input your library? In Project/Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies

Comment: I added like this: project-add-existing item, is this the right way?

Comment: 不对。在项目属性的linker里加，你再仔细找找。